# How do I use my iPhone 2G in Winamp without needing iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, winamp

Is there any method of using iPhone (2G) with Winamp without having iTunes installed?

Comment: have you found any solutions so far (more than 1 year later)?

Comment: no solution found yet: stuck to itunes :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you willing to consider alternatives to Winamp?

If so, [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) has iPod (and by extension iPhone) support. The help page starts off with the following:

> **iPod / iPhone Synchronization**
>
> **Prepare the iPod / iPhone**
>
> 1. Connect your iPod and run iTunes
> 2. Click Edit > Preferences and on the Syncing tab, enable 'Disable automatic
>      syncing for all iPhones and iPods'.
> 3. Click on your iPod in the iTunes tree and on the Summary tab
>
>    1. Disable 'Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected' and 'Open
>         iTunes when this iPod is connected'
>    2. Disable 'Sync only checked songs and videos'
>    3. Enable 'Manually manage music and videos' and 'Enable disk use'
> 4. Select the 'Music' tab in iTunes
>
>    1. Disable 'Sync Music'
>    2. Enable 'Display Album Artwork on your iPod'
> 5. On the Movies, TV Shows, and Podcasts tabs, disable the 'Sync
>      Movies', 'Sync TV Shows', 'Sync
>      Podcasts' options.
> 6. Eject the iPod and close iTunes
>
> If you are using an iPhone or iPod
>   Touch, do not uninstall iTunes.
>
> Note: In some cases it may be
>   necessary to delete existing content
>   from the device by using the iTunes
>   Updater to restore the device to its
>   factory condition.

It goes on to describe how to connect and sync using MediaMonkey so I won't reproduce it here.

It looks like you have to have iTunes installed at some point and there are cases where you need to keep it installed.

This procedure might be worth investigating with Winamp.

Comment: I used to use MediaMonkey as my default music player, but I definitively love winamp... And I don't want iTunes installed in my pc...

Comment: @Andi - well it appears that this approach won't work then, unless the MediaMonkey people are being ultra cautious. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like the [**CopyTrans Manager**](http://www.copytrans.net/copytransmanager.php)?

The feature list.

**Play iPod tracks directly on any PC**

- Listen to your iPod Touch music, audio books, podcasts
- Keep your iTunes alternative on your iPod
- Use your iPhone manager on every PC without installation

**Add music to iPod, videos & more**

- Add music, podcasts, audio books, videos, films and TV-shows to iPod or iPhone
- Drag & Drop songs directly from any folder to your iPod, iTouch and iPhone
- Add tracks from any PC to iPod, iPod Touch and iPhone

**Organize iPhone or iPod and manage playlists**

- Create iPod Touch playlists or edit existing ones
- Drag & Drop iPhone songs directly into iPhone playlists
- Import all album artwork automatically to your iPod or iPhone
- Edit track information (artist, album, ratings, genre, etc.)
- Search iPhone tracks by album, artist or anyway you want
- Synchronize iPod instantly or manually

**Remove iPod tracks & playlists**

- Remove tracks from your iPod playlists
- Remove iPod Touch playlists
- Delete iPhone tracks definitively

**Compatible with all iPod models**

```
* iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS up to firmware 3.x
* iPod Touch & iPod Touch 2G up to firmware 3.x
* iPod Nano up to iPod Nano 4G
* iPod Classic
* iPod Video
* iPod Shuffle up to iPod Shuffle 2G
* iPod Mini
* iPod Photo
```

**System requirements**

- Min. 128 MB of RAM
- Designed for Windows XP, Vista & Windows 7
- iPhone/iPod Touch: Quicktime and iPhone drivers needed

Comment: Needs previous iTunes installation

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://mlipod.sourceforge.net/wiki/IPhone_and_iPod_touch_support) plugin is what your looking for and it has instructions on how it can be done without installing iTunes.

It allows for the management and control of certain iPhone functions from within WinAMP.

However please note the limited support.

Comment: I have the ml_ipod plugin installed and it works fine with my iPod 5G... But it doesn't with the iPhone, probably because there is no way of using it in "disk mode"...